# Regex Function in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

Could any of you pls explain the following code. For eg., Why D,d is used for?

```
NOT(REGEX(Phone, "\\D*?(\\d\\D*?){10}"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double backslashes are used because of Java's string escaping rules. The pure regex means:

```
\D*?   # Match any number of non-digit characters (the "?" is useless here)
(      # Match...
 \d    # a single digit
 \D*?  # optionally followed by any number of non-digits (again, useless "?")
){10}  # Repeat the previous group 10 times.
```

So this regex matches any string that contains exactly ten digits (plus any number of other, non-digit characters).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the REGEX from the example in [Salesforce](http://na7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm), it's useless. It matches "this1234567890that" where "this" and "that" can be any value. I used: NOT( REGEX(Phone, "\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}|\d{10}")) to accomplish the desired behavior.

My version translates to:

```
\\(      # Match '('
[0-9]{3} # Match 3 digits
\\)      # Match ')' followed by a space 
[0-9]{3} # Match 3 digits
-        # Match hyphen
[0-9]{4} # Match 4 more digits
|\\d{10} # or match 10 digits instead of all the previous
```